# ModelState isvalid return false when using querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.2, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC application and I need to pass a vule from one page to another page , for that I have used query string using this code

```
@Url.Action("Create", "ValueMapping",new { templateID =ViewBag.TemplateId}
```

and I am retriving that velue in my controller. but the problem is that in my controller the Model.IsValid is returning false after passing the query string. Why it is happenning and what is the way out for this.

Action code parametrs are below

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ValueMappingId,ValueMappingTypeId,TemplateId,UseFor,SourceValue,DestinationValue,OrgAppSyncId,IsActive,CreatedOn,LastUpdatedOn")] ValueMapping valuemapping)
{}
```

Thanks
Utpal Maity

Comment: What are all the parameters for "Create" Action?

Comment: Are you expecting a model that has data validation attributes on it? If so is your model meet the requirements ? Any required field example ?

Comment: Modified the question and Given the code @SivananthamPadikkasu

Answer (score 0):

Is the `Url.Action` being used as the `action` attribute of a form? I'm assuming so, as a simple link is obviously not going to include all the data your model would need to be valid.

I'm also assuming that `TemplateId` is a required value, because that's the only thing that really makes sense. If you're doing a post, query strings are out. The post body is the source of data for a post request. Just add a hidden field to store the template id:

```
@Html.Hidden("TemplateId", ViewBag.TemplateId as string)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more please . My scenario is like this . My start page is Index page from where I can get "templateID" and I am navigating to Create page  where I will use the "TemplateID" in the controler . In this situation where I will use hidden field and how I will retrieve that.

Comment: Again, it depends on what you're doing. I'm assuming you have a form and are doing a post. If that's the case, then the hidden field goes in the form, and it will naturally bind on post to the model property or action param of the same name. If you've got a traditional link, that's really not going to work, so you pretty much need to switch to a form.

Comment: in my previous comment I have described you my scenario please suggest based on that situation and if possible please give some sample code. I am new in web development.